# Give an alias to eager loaded table columns

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I know I can select specific columns from eager loaded tables, but can I give them an alias? So for example:

```
Post::select('name as name1')
    ->with(['users' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'name as name2');
    }])
    ->get()
```

or

```
Post::select('name as name1')
   ->with('users:id,name as name2');
```

I would like to give it custom alias, not just to prepend table name. But either way, I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add aliases to the eagerly loaded column. What you're doing now seems correct, but you should also select the column that has a relationship with your `Post` class. As an example:

```php
Post::select('name as name1')
    ->with(['users' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'post_id', 'name as name2');
    }])
    ->get()
```

And of course, don't forget to add `hasMany` relationship in your `Post` class. For example:

```php
// app/Models/Post.php

...

class Post extends Model
{
    ...

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's cool. But in the final result I'm gonna have to iterate over `users` to get `name2` column. Is it possible to have that column as a first level property inside result, next to `name1`?

Comment: @nikname It seems that what you are doing now is the only way if you want to move/flatten the eagerly loaded column to the parent property. But if you avoid using loops, then using a [query builder with a join clause](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins) seems to be the right choice for now.

Comment: sorry but it does not seems to work with laravel 10.